# How to remove Windows Product Key from BIOS?

Tags: windows-8.1, bios, windows-activation, product-key, oem

I recently installed windows 8.1 on my new laptop. I want to transfer the product key from my old laptop to my new laptop. I tried removing the key from these commands:

```
slmgr /upk
slmgr /cpky
```

This removed the key and the cache from registry. However, my new laptop is still not accepting this key which I believe is due to the reason that this key is already present in the BIOS of my old laptop. I can still see this key by using this command:

```
powershell "(Get-WmiObject -query 'select * from SoftwareLicensingService').OA3xOriginalProductKey"
```

Is there any way to remove the key entirely from BIOS as well? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot, it is an OEM key which is not transferable, Windows will not activate on other hardware than the original it came on.

Comment: I also want to delete the activation key from bios. Did you manage to delete it?